# oneside in Memoir causing header trouble

Tags: memoir, double-sided, single-sided

Any ideas why the following works fine in the `twoside` version but creates headers with all section names "List of Tables" (incorrect) in the `oneside` version?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}                 
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\sffamily\small\leftmark}{}{\sffamily\small\rightmark}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\sffamily\small\rightmark}{}{\sffamily\small\leftmark}

\begin{document}

   \tableofcontents*
    \listoffigures*
    \listoftables*

    \pagestyle{mystyle}
    \blinddocument
    \section{Some section}
    \blindtext[8]   
\end{document}
```

This is how it appears in `oneside` (incorrect)

[image: incorrect section name]

This is how it appears in `twoside` (correct)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things in play here:

1. Under `oneside` only the `odd` design is used, the even one is ignored as odd vs even pages does not make any sense in a onesided design.
2. You have not made any marks for your style, this means the default `headings` marks are used, and these only write to `\rightmark` under `oneside`

I'm actually a little surprised that List of Tables ends up in `\leftmark`.

You could try

```
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother
```

in what ever combination of `both`, `left`, `right` that suits you.

---

Actually there is a small bug in the current `memoir`. Under `oneside` `\lofmark` and `\lotmark` ends up writing to both left and right mark even though the defaults `headings` style sets it to only write to the right mark.

This is going to be fixed in the next release (unknown) date, in the meantime you can issue `\pagetyle{headings}` in the preamble, to get the style provided by it.